# Search for sku of custom option in shop

Tags: magento2, custom-options, catalogsearch

I want to configure the **search** to search for a **SKU** of a **custom option**.

I got different **products** with custom options and a related SKU. I want to get it working, that a customer can search for the SKU of a custom option, but it's **not generally implemented in magento 2** and it's not set as an attribute so I can change it in the attributes to search for that particular sku.

Does somebody know how to do this to get that custom option SKU to index with the MYSQL search.

Regards